How to re-order the responses when plotting Likert scale data in R?
I have survey data that I am trying to plot in R but the issue is that the responses appear in alphabetical order as seen in the graph below:

I would like the responses to be in the order "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither Disagree nor Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree".
I tried re-ordering the factors for each column of the dataframe using
levels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither Disagree nor Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")
but this collapsed the dataframe into a single column with no data.
Here is the code I used that returns the plot with the responses in alphabetical order:
attitudes <- sub_survey %>% 
  select(i_sub_no_perm_job,                  
         i_sub_flexibility,                  
         i_sub_help_local_school,            
         amnt_sub_wrk_incrsing,              
         i_wrk_max_avlbl_hrs,                
         sub_wrk_not_attractive_low_pay) %>% 
  rename("I provide substitution work because I can't find a permanent job" = i_sub_no_perm_job,                
         "I provide substitution work because I enjoy the flexibility" = i_sub_flexibility,             
         "I provide substitution work because I want to help out my local school" = i_sub_help_local_school,                    
         "I believe the amount of substitution work available is increasing in my area" = amnt_sub_wrk_incrsing,                    
         "I work the maximum number of substitution hours I am available for" = i_wrk_max_avlbl_hrs,                    
         "Substitution work is not an attractive option for me as the pay/conditions are poor" = sub_wrk_not_attractive_low_pay) %>% 
  na.omit()

attitudes[] <- lapply(attitudes, factor)

plot(likert(attitudes),legend.position = "right")

Here is the output of dput using the first four rows:
`structure(list(`I provide substitution work because I can't find a 
permanent job` = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("Agree", "Disagree", "Neither Disagree nor 
Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree"), class = "factor"), `I provide 
substitution work because I enjoy the flexibility` = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 1L), levels = c("Agree", "Disagree", "Neither Disagree nor 
Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree"), class = "factor"), `I provide 
substitution work because I want to help out my local school` = 
structure(c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Agree", "Disagree", "Neither Disagree nor 
Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree"), class = "factor"), `I believe 
the amount of substitution work available is increasing in my area` = 
structure(c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), levels = c("Agree", "Disagree", "Neither Disagree nor 
Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree"), class = "factor"), `I work the 
maximum number of substitution hours I am available for` = 
structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Agree", "Disagree", "Neither Disagree nor 
Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree"), class = "factor"), 
`Substitution 
work is not an attractive option for me as the pay/conditions are poor` 
= structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Agree", "Disagree", "Neither Disagree nor 
Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree"), class = "factor")), row.names = 
c(NA, 
-4L), na.action = structure(293:298, names = c("293", "294", 
"295", "296", "297", "298"), class = "omit"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))`


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data.

Not sure what you have tried. Simply setting the levels appropriately works fine for me. But note that one of the levels contains a line break "\n" which you have to account for. Additionally at least for the version of likert I use (1.3.5) I had to convert your tibble to an ordinary data frame:
library(likert)

packageVersion("likert")
#> [1] '1.3.5'

attitudes <- as.data.frame(attitudes)

attitudes[] <- lapply(attitudes, factor,
  levels = c(
    "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree",
    "Neither Disagree nor\nAgree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"
  )
)

plot(likert(attitudes), legend.position = "right")


